# css3 animation safari not working

Tags: html, css

I created a radar CSS3 animation for website its working fine almost all browser except safari browser latest version it does not showing border. If we add background color its showing but border is not visible. Been digging around for some while, but cant find solution. I'm talking about border in keyframes in 0% and 100%.

here is HTML and CSS3

```css
.radar-desktop {
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 top: auto;
 right: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 display: block;
 margin: 0px auto;
 flex: unset !important;
 position: relative;
}

.wave-desktop {
 width: 0%;
 padding-top: 0%;
 background-color: transparent;
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 border-radius: 50%;
 max-width: 100%;
 max-height: 100%;
}

.wave-desktop.time1-desktop {
 background-image: none;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: 120px 120px;
 width: 120px;
 height: 120px;
 background-position: center;
}

.wave-desktop.time2-desktop {
 -webkit-animation: radardesktop 4s cubic-bezier(0.6, 0.96, 0.9, 0.95) 0s infinite;
 animation: radardesktop 4s cubic-bezier(0.6, 0.96, 0.9, 0.95) 0s infinite;
}

.wave-desktop.time3-desktop {
 -webkit-animation: radardesktop 4s cubic-bezier(0.6, 0.96, 0.9, 0.95) 1s infinite;
 animation: radardesktop 4s cubic-bezier(0.6, 0.96, 0.9, 0.95) 1s infinite;
}

.wave-desktop.time4-desktop {
 -webkit-animation: radardesktop 4s cubic-bezier(0.6, 0.96, 0.9, 0.95) 2s infinite;
 animation: radardesktop 4s cubic-bezier(0.6, 0.96, 0.9, 0.95) 2s infinite;
}

.wave-desktop.time5-desktop {
 -webkit-animation: radardesktop 4s cubic-bezier(0.6, 0.96, 0.9, 0.95) 2s infinite;
 animation: radardesktop 4s cubic-bezier(0.6, 0.96, 0.9, 0.95) 2s infinite;
}

.wave-desktop.time6-desktop {
 -webkit-animation: radardesktop 4s cubic-bezier(0.6, 0.96, 0.9, 0.95) 3s infinite;
 animation: radardesktop 4s cubic-bezier(0.6, 0.96, 0.9, 0.95) 3s infinite;
}

.wave-desktop.time7-desktop {
 -webkit-animation: radardesktop 4s cubic-bezier(0.6, 0.96, 0.9, 0.95) 3s infinite;
 animation: radardesktop 4s cubic-bezier(0.6, 0.96, 0.9, 0.95) 3s infinite;
}

.wave-desktop.time8-desktop {
 -webkit-animation: radardesktop 4s cubic-bezier(0.6, 0.96, 0.9, 0.95) 4s infinite;
 animation: radardesktop 4s cubic-bezier(0.6, 0.96, 0.9, 0.95) 4s infinite;
 min-width: 150px;
 min-height: 150px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes radardesktop {
 0% {
  width: 0%;
  padding-top: 0%;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  z-index: 4;
 }
 25% {
  z-index: 3;
 }
 50% {
  z-index: 2;
 }
 75% {
  z-index: 1;
 }
 100% {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
 }
}

@keyframes radardesktop {
 0% {
  width: 0%;
  padding-top: 0%;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  z-index: 4;
 }
 25% {
  z-index: 3;
 }
 50% {
  z-index: 2;
 }
 75% {
  z-index: 1;
 }
 100% {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="radar-desktop">
 <div class="wave-desktop time1-desktop"></div>
 <div class="wave-desktop time2-desktop"></div>
 <div class="wave-desktop time3-desktop"></div>
 <div class="wave-desktop time4-desktop"></div>
 <div class="wave-desktop time5-desktop"></div>
 <div class="wave-desktop time6-desktop"></div>
 <div class="wave-desktop time7-desktop"></div>
 <div class="wave-desktop time8-desktop"></div>
</div>
```

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.

```
.wave-desktop {
    width: 0%;
    padding-top: 0%;
    background-color: transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    border-radius: 50%;
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
}
    .wave-desktop.time1-desktop {
        background-image: none;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 120px 120px;
        width:120px;
        height:120px;
        background-position: center;

    }
    .wave-desktop.time2-desktop {
      -webkit-animation: radardesktop 4s cubic-bezier(0.6, 0.96, 0.9, 0.95) 0s infinite;
              animation: radardesktop 4s cubic-bezier(0.6, 0.96, 0.9, 0.95) 0s infinite;
              border:1px solid;
    }
    .wave-desktop.time3-desktop {
      -webkit-animation: radardesktop 4s cubic-bezier(0.6, 0.96, 0.9, 0.95) 1s infinite;
              animation: radardesktop 4s cubic-bezier(0.6, 0.96, 0.9, 0.95) 1s infinite;
              border:1px solid;
    }
    .wave-desktop.time4-desktop {
      -webkit-animation: radardesktop 4s cubic-bezier(0.6, 0.96, 0.9, 0.95) 2s infinite;
              animation: radardesktop 4s cubic-bezier(0.6, 0.96, 0.9, 0.95) 2s infinite;
              border:1px solid;
    }
    .wave-desktop.time5-desktop {
      -webkit-animation: radardesktop 4s cubic-bezier(0.6, 0.96, 0.9, 0.95) 2s infinite;
              animation: radardesktop 4s cubic-bezier(0.6, 0.96, 0.9, 0.95) 2s infinite;
              border:1px solid;
    }
    .wave-desktop.time6-desktop {
      -webkit-animation: radardesktop 4s cubic-bezier(0.6, 0.96, 0.9, 0.95) 3s infinite;
              animation: radardesktop 4s cubic-bezier(0.6, 0.96, 0.9, 0.95) 3s infinite;
              border:1px solid;
    }
    .wave-desktop.time7-desktop {
      -webkit-animation: radardesktop 4s cubic-bezier(0.6, 0.96, 0.9, 0.95) 3s infinite;
              animation: radardesktop 4s cubic-bezier(0.6, 0.96, 0.9, 0.95) 3s infinite;
              border:1px solid;
    }
    .wave-desktop.time8-desktop {
      -webkit-animation: radardesktop 4s cubic-bezier(0.6, 0.96, 0.9, 0.95) 4s infinite;
              animation: radardesktop 4s cubic-bezier(0.6, 0.96, 0.9, 0.95) 4s infinite;
              border:1px solid;
              min-width: 150px;
              min-height:150px;
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes radardesktop {
      0% {
        width: 0%;
        padding-top: 0%;
        border-color: #D9D9D9;
        background-color: transparent;
        z-index: 4;
      }
      25% {
        z-index: 3;
      }
      50% {
        z-index: 2;
      }
      75% {
        z-index: 1;
      }
      100% {
        width: 100%;
        padding-top: 100%;
        border-color: #D9D9D9;
        background-color: transparent;
      }
    }

    @keyframes radardesktop {
      0% {
        width: 0%;
        padding-top: 0%;
        border-color: #D9D9D9;
        background-color: transparent;
        z-index: 4;
      }
      25% {
        z-index: 3;
      }
      50% {
        z-index: 2;
      }
      75% {
        z-index: 1;
      }
      100% {
        width: 100%;
        padding-top: 100%;
        border-color: #D9D9D9;
        background-color: transparent;
      }
    }
```